# I'm trying to trigger hover of DOM element by JS, but failed. It seems this is impossible. But why Chrome could do it? How?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, hover

I'm trying to trigger hover of DOM element by JS, but failed. It seems this is impossible. 
I know there is a way to do this is create a class with hover function and do add/remove this class to achieve the same stage.
But why Chrome could do it? How?

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it. It's not a [trusted event](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#trusted-events).

You can just simulate it with classes manually.

Browser can do it throw internal API/Methods.

You can check an [source code](https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend) of Chrome devtools for this [action](https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend/blob/a023ca2df2dec8722bf612a9134ea670f103bdac/front_end/elements/ElementStatePaneWidget.js#L25).

It's triggers [method `forcePseudoState`](https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend/blob/49cdbeaac36dc0c257d5486daf55f15c90c3d0a3/front_end/sdk/CSSModel.js#L429) for the CSSModel.